# How to horizontally space bootstrap form

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

Here's how my django filter form looks like:

[image]

I need to horizontally space them a little so that 'Name contains' and the search bar, and 'result' etc are not glued to each other.

Here's my html code:

```
  <form action="" method="get" class="form-inline text-white justify-content-center mx-3">
       {{myfilter.form|bootstrap}}

     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
       Search</button>

  </form>
```

I have tried adding `m-3`, `mx-3` etc but they don't work. Little help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I have to to explain you that you apply m-3 or mx-3 class to the form tag so that the mx-3 gives margin to form tab only and the `Name contains` and the `search bar` and `result` etc. are the child element of the form.

So the mx-3 class will work if you add it to the particular element.

Now, the solution for your problem should be:

If you put `class="mx-3"` to every form element.

Or you have to apply CSS as follow.

*HTML*

```
<form action="" method="get" class="weekly_calls_form form-inline text-white justify-content-center">
  {{myfilter.form|bootstrap}}
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

I have added my custom class to the form tag named `weekly_calls_form`

Now using this class I apply CSS to all element of the form tag.

*CSS*

```
.weekly_calls_form > *{
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

This CSS apply to all the direct child elements of form.

Comment: one question; how to add some space between the label and search bar? current css does not take care of that space

Comment: you want more space between label and search bar, then target that label using parent class and increase margin value for labels

Comment: But i don't have a label tag here?

Comment: then I think you have direct text in form right?

Comment: then you can't apply CSS to them do one thing .weekly_calls_form > *{margin: 0px 10px;} use this css this make your space double then now, this works perfect I think.